# Get the parent of a class in D

Tags: d, dmd

How can I get the base type of a class from outside that class? I found the trait `parent` in the docs, but I'm not sure how to use it.

```
module test;
import std.stdio;

class A {}
class B : A { }

void main() {
    writeln(typeid(__traits(parent, B)));
    writeln(typeid(__traits(parent, test.B))); // try prefixing with module name
}
```

I would expect to get A in at least the second case, but this prints

```
void
void
```

Ideally I'd like to assign the base class of some class T to an alias and use that as I would any other type. For example:

```
alias T = __traits(parent, V);
T t = new T();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`__traits(parent, ...)`](http://dlang.org/traits.html#parent) is about scopes. `__traits(parent, B)` is the `test` module. The documentation is too vague about this.

[`std.traits.BaseClassesTuple`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#BaseClassesTuple) is what you're looking for.

As a general rule, look in `std.traits` first. The ugly `__traits` shouldn't come up in user code often.

---

Some working sample code:

```
module test;
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

class A {}
class B : A { }

void main() {
    writeln(__traits(parent, B).stringof); /* prints "module test" */
    alias Bases = BaseClassesTuple!B;
    writeln(Bases.stringof); /* prints "(A, Object)" */
    static assert(Bases.length > 0);
    alias T = Bases[0];
    auto t = new T;
}
```